# IPE does not work

Tags: ipe

For my research internship I need to draw figures to include in my report. I was told IPE otfried was the best to use, so I downloaded it, extracted it, and tried to open it. It seems to have a slight waiting time and then nothing happens, I have no idea why. I tried running it with admin rights it does not change anything. I'm actually a bit rushed since I have a deadline.

I'm on W10, I also did try to turn off the windows anti-virus.

It seems that "iperender.exe" is the only file that can launch, for some reason.

If you know how to run it please help me !

If you have another program which does something similar also.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Did you get some error messages?

Comment: (1) What operating system? (2) Can you open a commandline, navigate to where the IPE binary that you downloaded is stored, and run `ipe` and see if there are any error messages?

Comment: Mensch: Thanks ! No error message, I simply launch the ipe.exe in the bin file and it does nothing.

Comment: Willie Wong: (1) Windows 10. (2) I did that altough I'm not too familiar with using commandlines. I went to the bin directory and typed "run ipe.exe" and still nothing happens ( I did that running the commandline with admin rights).

Comment: You can also try [inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) if you are still finding issues with ipe. You can use the [TexText](https://inkscape.org/~jcwinkler/%E2%98%85textext) extension if you need to render latex content in the image.

Comment: Thanks Zxcvasfd, I'll probably do that since I have no solution...

Comment: @Rafaël did you get any solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: @Mrcrg I did find a solution, I simply didn't open the right folder for some reason. The correct one is supposed to be in "Programs" in your C:\data